# Can't comment on the blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

I want to add a comment on the [latest blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/05/introducing-beyond-coding-free-professional-skills-training-for-emerging-devs-in-nyc/?cb=1).

But I get

> To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

First, I enter text:

> [image]

Then, I click `Submit`, and get:

> [image]

Can this be fixed ?

Comment: Should probably post this on Meta.SO, but now it's here already..

Comment: The blog is for the whole network, not just Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be fixed now. We upgraded the blog and apparently broke the recaptcha keys over the weekend.

Comment: Thanks, it works now !