# Render question title on internal link in comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown-rendering, internal-links

EDIT: totally agree with the duplicate. Sorry for taking your time: I did search for 10 minutes before posting this. Cheers.

When I link to another question from a question or answer, the rendered markdown shows the title of the other question, e.g.:

[Can't comment on the blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255985/cant-comment-on-the-blog)

But when we do it for comments, it does not (see my comment below).

I wish it would also render the question title on comments, as it really helps readers to find the new content.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255985/cant-comment-on-the-blog

Comment: @MARamezani placeholder which for some reason came back, correcting

Comment: seeing this bug across the network. Reporting.

Comment: Re the duplicate is fine, it happens sometimes. No probs if you did search :) But just for future reference, when you edit a closed post it goes into a review queue for users to decide if it needs re-opening due to the edit. Again, no probs, but just so you know for next time. A comment is preferred :)

Comment: @James ah, thanks for the note! :-) I've never touched the review queue much, but I'm an avid editor. Gotta do that some day to pay my debts.