# What's your * question? Be specific

Tags: bug, questions, title

I'm seeing questions with this title across the network, [here (edited in grace)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255990/whats-your-bug-feature-request-or-meta-discussion-topic-be-specific), [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/614520/1) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/618147/1). [Here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/617474/1), [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/618348/1), [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/revisions/10904/1), [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/revisions/5601/1) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/614446/1). Oh, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/176278/1) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/577382/1) as well. Another [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/565621/1).

Ask Ubuntu report about it [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13918/186134).

At first I thought it was users typing it out, but see [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255990/whats-your-bug-feature-request-or-meta-discussion-topic-be-specific#comment833553_255990):

> @MARamezani placeholder which for some reason came back, correcting

and [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617474/can-not-get-udev-to-execute-cutom-rules#comment872067_617474):

> haha I gave it a title don't know what happened there :)

I'm not so sure users are typing it out...

---

Have a look at [this wildcard network search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%27s%20your%20*%20question%3F%20Be%20specific%22).

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ not weird at all. That's the title placeholder, looks like it's being submitted somehow. Bug of course, but not very weird. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was a little surprised at first, I thought that people were actually typing it out - I mean that's more effort than most `ubantu prob plz hlps` titles!

Comment: @Tim, nope - couldn't reproduce with Chrome but surely it happens with at least one browser.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I tried with JS off and it still didn't break so I'm not sure... Some extension that autofills placeholder...? Seems unlikely.

Comment: Well it at least got me. If it was April 1st then it would've made some sense.... Maybe the SE calendar is a little off.

Comment: @MARamezani do you have java script enabled? Anything funny happen? Slow internet?

Comment: Is there an option "all of the above"?

Comment: This could be like people who paste "quality standards" text into their questions to pad out the length and fool the filter.

Comment: @Won't the comments suggest it's the system, not them...?

Comment: Do I care what the comments suggest?  NO! I only care about truth, justice, and a nice double IPA!

Comment: Calling the cavalry...

Comment: Wait. Did you realize that those weird titles are *not* the placeholders exactly? The placeholders have a dot at the end.

Comment: @nicael ahh, I didn't notice... Hmm. Will edit in when I have more time.

Comment: Your search didn't load for me..... loading.......

Comment: The worst part is few of them have contact info, so we cannot just ask them. And excellent catch @nicael